# How to insert my own code to Netbeans Gui Builder?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jeditorpane

I found on the Web code: http://java-sl.com/tip_autoreplace_smiles.html which I edited to my own needs, take a look:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Emotes extends JEditorPane {

    public Emotes() {
        super();
        this.setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit());
        this.initListener();
    }

    private void replace (String text, StyledDocument doc, ImageIcon icon, int start, String what) throws BadLocationException
    {
        int i = text.indexOf(what);
        while(i >= 0) 
        {
            final SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet(doc.getCharacterElement(start+i).getAttributes());
            if (StyleConstants.getIcon(attrs) == null)
            {
                StyleConstants.setIcon(attrs, icon);
                doc.remove(start+i, what.length());
                doc.insertString(start+i,what, attrs);
            }
            i = text.indexOf(what, i+what.length());
        }
    }

    private void initListener() {
        getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
                final DocumentEvent e=event;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (e.getDocument() instanceof StyledDocument) {
                            try {
                                StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument)e.getDocument();
                                int start= Utilities.getRowStart(Emotes.this,Math.max(0,e.getOffset()-1));
                                int end=Utilities.getWordStart(Emotes.this,e.getOffset()+e.getLength());
                                String text=doc.getText(start, end-start);


                                replace(text, doc, createEmoticon("wink.png"), start, ";)");
                                replace(text, doc, createEmoticon("wink.png"), start, "<wink>");
                                replace(text, doc, createEmoticon("sad.png"), start, ":(");
                                replace(text, doc, createEmoticon("sad.png"), start, "<sad>");
                                replace(text, doc, createEmoticon("smile.png"), start, ":)");
                                replace(text, doc, createEmoticon("smile.png"), start, "<smile>");

                            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    static ImageIcon createEmoticon(String icon)
    {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(icon));
            Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
            ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }catch (IOException ex)
        {
        }
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }
}
```

which works great. But I created in Netbeans a new GUI (JDialog Window) with JEditorPane on it, where I want to use this feature on JDialog window:

[image]

but it doesnt want to work at all. When I type ":)" its not changing in an image.

Just try to run that code:

```
public class NewJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /** Creates new form NewJDialog */
    public NewJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jEditorPane1 = new Emotes();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jEditorPane1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 229, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                NewJDialog dialog = new NewJDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JEditorPane jEditorPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

And the emotes I use are: [image] [image] [image]

Comment: please mention some level of detail for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application is compiled to a .jar file. Normal File I/O then does not take (the current directory varies depending on the call). Take the images out of the jar/class path as:

```
        img = ImageIO.read(Emotes.class.getResourceAsStream(icon));
```

Comment: I was testing the code and I saw the same problem. At first the createEmoticon(String icon) was always giving NullPointerException in the line "return new ImageIcon(img);". Then I created an image called "smile.gif", put it in my file system and changed the path used to create the File to point to my new image. Also, I commented all lines that generate images different than "smile.gif" and it worked fine. I think she is getting the error when she tries to load  the images from inside the .jar using a File instance. I think your answer will solve the problem

Comment: @JoopEggen : guys you're right, it was the path issue. It works fine now, cheerz!:)